# SVG images grow and create scrollbars when on the server

Tags: html, css, javascript, svg

Okay so I embedded some SVG images into my page and opened it locally on Chrome and it looked fine.

I upload the same file to the server and look at the page online and the SVG images have grown by maybe 5-10% and are surrounded by scroll bars like they are overflowing.

I think it probably has to do with my lack of knowledge on how SVG and Embed work. What's really puzzling me though, is that it works fine locally. (I have cache disabled.)

Help?
Thanks.

Edit: code

HTML:

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" src="content/web-logo.svg"/>
```

There's no CSS on the image.

I'm not sure if I was just wrong before or if I changed something I'm not aware of, but it doesn't appear to be actually changing size anymore.

It just decides to stuff it into a scrollbox.

pic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt1aufi7nl1fpyi/svg-problem.png

Comment: I tend to agree here, the issue may be that your browser is zooming in on the image (this is remembered in Chrome at least). In chrome `CTRL+0` will give you the actual size.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Everything else on the page is the size it should be. The scroll bars are created AROUND the images. Like overflow:scroll. I am on Chrome, and I've pressed Ctrl-0. The page is at normal size.

Comment: ahh, ok. just a thought. Then, are you possibly able to provide us with an example of the SVG image

Comment: Here's the code for the SVG and what the image is supposed to look like: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwqzK.

And here it is on my test-site: [link](http://www.ultravectroid.com)

Comment: I think the problem is that for some reason the embed element is choosing to be 300 x 150. I want it to just fit the content, like a div. I tried manually sizing the embed element by id in CSS to no avail.

Comment: did you try setting the height and width attributes on the embed tag?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your browser; try `"CTRL -"` (Control and minus sign) to zoom the page out. Post back your results, and if it needs to be looked at closer.